# PHP str_replace issue

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Ok, have this code here:

```
$search = array('{POST}', '{post}');
$replace = $recent['body'];
$message = str_replace($search, $replace, html_entity_decode($params['post_html']));
```

`$params[post_html']` is a variable that holds the users input with either {POST} or {post} defined, for example could be like this, after it gets decoded ofcourse:

```
<span class="upperframe">
  <span></span>
</span>
<div class="roundframe dp_control_flow">
{POST}
</div>
<span class="lowerframe">
  <span></span>
</span>
```

Anyways, the problem I'm facing here is, for some reason, `str_replace` is ALSO replacing and `{POST}` or `{post}` strings within the replace parameter:  `$recent['body']`  This should NOT happen, how can I fix this so that it doesn't perform a replace on the thing that needs to be replacing `{POST}` or `{post}`?

I did not expect this function to do replaces within the replace variable.  OUCH.  Is there a way around this?  Do I have to use a preg_replace instead?  If so, can someone help me with a regex for this?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: your array contains both 'POST' and 'post' so if either are there it will replace it.

Comment: yes, but why is it replacing it within the replacement parameter?  To me, it should only replace it within the subject parameter.  I suppose I'll just go with 1 of them than...  Thanks anyways.

Comment: I suppose you could do a preg_match with it, but that does seem like odd behavior

Comment: Actually, after just testing it, it does work as you expected it to.  You must be running that str_replace somewhere else?  Also str_ireplace is an insensitive search.

Comment: You didn't test it good enough.  For example, if I have `{POST}` within the `$params['post_html']` variable, but than I have `{post}` within the `$recent['body']` variable, it echos out `$recent['body']` variable again, though IMO, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use str_ireplace() then you don't need the array for the search and the issue is solved.

```
$recent['body']="*test* {post} *test*";
$params['post_html']="foo {POST} bar";


//$search = array('{POST}', '{post}');
$search = '{post}';
$replace = $recent['body'];
$message = str_ireplace($search, $replace, html_entity_decode($params['post_html']));

echo $message; 


//with array
// foo *test* *test* {post} *test* *test* bar

//without
//foo *test* {post} *test* bar
```

Comment: yeah, but this is only PHP 5 compatible, I'm trying to support older PHP also, just in case.  It's all good anyways, will give you an useful answer for your attempt.  I've just changed it to use `{POST}` only.

Comment: older php versiosn should *not* be supported as "Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31"

Comment: Ohh, didn't know this, thanks will mark this as my answer than.  Cheers :)